# Adding swip functionallty to flex items on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple flex container with 3 items next to each other, on mobile version i want to keep the same layout and instead of changing the flex direction to column, i want to keep them next to teach others and add swipe to see next items

Example with images

On Desktop ( which is fine i know how to do that )
[image]

On mobile ( i want to keep them next to each other and swipe on screen to see next items)
[image]

html

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
```

css

```
.parent {
  width: 98vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  width: 33%;  
  height: 500px;
  background: black;
}
```

Real example
https://mouthwash.co/

On Desktop
[image]

On mobile ( so i have to swipe to see the other items )

[image]

Comment: On mobile, each child would take 100% of the parent's width, not 33%, so you can write that in a media query. Also, enable `flex-wrap:wrap` so the children stack up vertically

Comment: @JeremyThille so the drag functionality is added automatically on mobile devices ?

Comment: Drag or scroll? Drag is hard to achieve (to reorder items in the view), but scroll is done automatically, with `overflow-y: auto`

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm sorry if i'm using the wrong words, yes i mean touch and swipe to see the hidden items i don't know this is drag or just scroll

Comment: Aaaaah I understand better. You want all children items in a row, left to right, and swipe left one by one to go through them. A simple horizontal scrolling is achieved very easily with `overflow-x:auto`. If you want the items to "stick" and neatly center themselves as you swipe, or auto-swipe every few seconds, you'll need a carousel plugin/library. Have a look at things like [Glide](https://glidejs.com/) or [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)